# Why do you throw me as an invalid form when the values of the fields are correct in the POST?

Tags: python, html, django, ajax, django-forms

I have the following code, that when I execute the form of localities it throws me that the form is not valid (for the rest it works well).
If you can see, the form uses chained dropdowns)
The fields that correspond to the model are loaded correctly.
All the rest (which I obviously didn't put the code) works wonders
OBS: Note that the keys are programmed and work correctly.

I would appreciate if you can help me.
Sorry my english.

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model  

class paises(models.Model):
    cpais = models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key=True)
    pais = models.CharField('País',unique=True, max_length=30, blank = False, null = False)
    SINO = (('Si', 'Si'), ('No', 'No'))
    defecto = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SINO, default='No')
    vigente = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SINO, default='Si')
    fmodi = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    usumodi = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank = True, null = False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'País'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Países'
        ordering = ['pais']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pais

class provincias(models.Model):
    cprovincia = models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key=True)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = False, null = False)
    cpais = models.ForeignKey(paises, on_delete = models.CASCADE,blank = True, null = True)
    SINO = (('Si', 'Si'), ('No', 'No'))
    defecto = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SINO, default='No')
    vigente = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SINO, default='No')
    fmodi = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    usumodi = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank = True, null = False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Provincia'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Provincias'
        ordering = ['provincia']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.provincia

class localidades(models.Model):
    clocalidad = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary_key=True)
    localidad = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = False, null = False)
    cprovincia = models.ForeignKey(provincias, on_delete = models.CASCADE,blank = True, null = True)
    cpais = models.ForeignKey(paises, on_delete = models.CASCADE,blank = True, null = True)
    cp = models.CharField(max_length = 5, blank = False, null = False)
    SINO = (('Si', 'Si'), ('No', 'No'))
    defecto = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SINO, default='No')
    SINO = (('Si', 'Si'), ('No', 'No'))
    vigente = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SINO, default='No')
    fmodi = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    usumodi = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank = True, null = False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Localidad'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Localidades'
        ordering = ['localidad']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.localidad
```

urls.py:

```py
#--------------------------------- Localidades ---------------------------    
    path('localidades',Localidad_List.as_view(), name = 'localidad_listar'),
    path('localidad_nuevo',Localidad_Crear.as_view(), name = 'localidad_crear'),
    path('localidad_editar/<pk>/',Localidad_Edit.as_view(), name = 'localidad_editar'),
    path('localidad_eliminar/<pk>/',Localidad_Delete.as_view(), name = 'localidad_eliminar'),    
    path('ajax/provincias/', provincia_load, name = 'ajax_provincias'),
```

localidades_vistas.py:

```py
class Localidad_List(ListView):
    model = localidades
    template_name = 'general/localidad_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        buscar = self.request.GET.get('buscalo')
        if buscar:
            object_list = localidades.objects.filter(localidad__contains = buscar)
        else:
            object_list = localidades.objects.all()
        return object_list

class Localidad_Crear(CreateView):
    model = localidades
    form_class = LocalidadForm
    template_name = 'general/localidad_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('general:localidad_listar')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            modelo = form.save(commit=False)
            modelo.clocalidad = localidad_max() #'99'
            usuario = self.request.user
            modelo.usumodi = str(usuario)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return HttpResponse(reverse('general:localidad_listar'))

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('general:localidad_listar')

class Localidad_Edit(UpdateView):
    model = localidades
    form_class = LocalidadForm
    template_name = 'general/localidad_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('general:localidad_listar')

class Localidad_Delete(DeleteView):
    model = localidades
    template_name = 'general/localidad_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('general:localidad_listar')      

def localidad_max():
    try:
        cvalor = localidades.objects.latest('clocalidad').clocalidad
    except:
        cvalor = '0'

    print(cvalor)
    cvalor = str(int(cvalor) + 1)
    return cvalor.zfill(5)

def provincia_load(request):
    cpais = request.GET.get('cpais')
    xprovincias = provincias.objects.filter(cpais = cpais).order_by('provincia')
    return render(request,'general/combo_provincia.html', {'provincias':xprovincias})
```

forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import paises, provincias, localidades

class LocalidadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = localidades
        search_fields = ['localidad']

        fields = [
            'localidad',
            'cp',
            'cpais',
            'cprovincia',
            'vigente',
        ]

        labels = {
            'localidad' : 'Localidad',
            'cp' : 'Cod. Postal',
            'cpais' : 'País',
            'cprovincia' : 'Provincia',
            'vigente' : 'Vigente',
        }
        widget= {
            #'localidad' :forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            #'cp' :forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            #'cpais' :forms.Select(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
            #'cprovincia' :forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None),
            # 'vigente' :forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cprovincia'].queryset = provincias.objects.none()
        if 'cpais' in self.data:
            try:
                cpais = int(self.data.get('cpais'))
                self.fields['cprovincia'].queryset = provincias.objects.filter(cpais = cpais).order_by('provincia')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['cprovincia'].queryset = self.instance.cpais.provincias_set.order_by('provincia')
```

combo_provincia.html

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for provincia in provincias %}
    <option value="{{ provincia.cprovincia }}">{{ provincia.provincia }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

localidad_form.html

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">

    <form method="post" id="Localidad_Form" data-provincias-url="{% url 'general:ajax_provincias' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p}}
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type= "submit">Guardar</button>
        <h5>{{ localidades.cprovincia }}</h5>
        {#  #}
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_cpais").change(function () {

            var url = $("#Localidad_Form").attr("data-provincias-url");  
            var paisId = $(this).val();  
            $.ajax({                       
            url: url,                    
            data: {
                'cpais': paisId       
                },
            success: function (data) {   
                $("#id_cprovincia").html(data);  
                            }
            }); 
        });
    //});
    </script>


</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block filtros %}
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{% url 'general:provincia_crear' %}">Agregar Provincia</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{% url 'general:pais_crear' %}">Agregar País</a>
    </td>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What errors do you get when printing `form.errors`?

Comment: `@KrazyMax`, in the ELSE of the form.is_invalid I print the value of cpais ('01'), cprovincia ('005'), and  `form.errors` : {'cprovincia': [ValidationError (['Select a valid option. The selected option is not one of the available. '])]}

Comment: Ok, so there is an error we can try to fix. But for now, too much information in your post, too many things to read. Which view/call make the error appear? Can you clean unnecessary classes please?

Comment: in the view `Localidad_Crear(CreateView)` ( `localidades_vistas.py `)